# Will Optical communications be possible between Columbus' Ka-band (COLKa) Terminal at the ISS and EDRS?

Tags: iss, communication-satellite, esa, optical-communication

The BBC's [British radio antenna to arrive at space station](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-51536246) says:

> The new fridge-sized terminal will route video, voice and data to the ground through satellites that are actually higher in the sky than the ISS.
>
> On occasions, these will continue to be the nodes in the American Tracking and Data Relay Satellite System (TDRSS), but the capacity is now there to go through a European alternative as well.
>
> [The European Data Relay System (EDRS)](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-49240745) only has one satellite operating at the moment but will soon have a second.
>
> This will afford the possibility of tens of minutes of dedicated, high-bandwidth connectivity for the Columbus lab on every 90-minute orbit of the Earth made by the station.
>
> Astronauts are expected to use COLKa to video-call scientists who have experiments running on the ISS, and to make "welfare" connections with family and friends on Earth.

If I understand correctly, COLKa means the Ka-band communications channel for Columbus lab.

The linked article in the quote is titled [Europe launches second EDRS ***space laser satellite***](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-49240745) and says:

> The 3-tonne EDRS-C satellite also hosts a Ka-band radio frequency payload for the London-based Avanti telecommunications company.
>
> Avanti calls the payload Hylas-3 and will be using it to deliver broadband and other data services to markets in Europe, the Middle East and Africa.

**Question:** So certainly some of the communications from the European antenna on the ISS's Columbus to EDRS will be via Ka-band, but I'd like to know if at least the hardware is now there for optical communication between the two as well.

**A caution:** the acronym EDRS can be short for [European Data Relay System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Data_Relay_System) as well as for [European Data Relay Satellite](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/European_Data_Relay_Satellite).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the COLKa (Columbus Ka-band antenna) provides only Ka-band communications.

This paper, while focused on the thermal design, provides the best overview of the system I have found: [Columbus Ka-band Terminal thermal control -  a compact design for varying conditions](https://ttu-ir.tdl.org/bitstream/handle/2346/67542/ICES_2016_125.pdf?sequence=1)

> It  is  made  up  of  a  steerable  antenna,  RF  signal  processing 
>   assemblies  (LNAs, frequency   converters,   etc.),   digital   signal
>   processing   assemblies   (digital   modulators   and   digital  demodulators), Command and Data Handling assemblies (PIAU), DC power
>   conditioning assemblies (PDU), micro-wave filters, waveguides
>   inter-connects, co-axial cable inter-connects, high speed digital
>   cable inter-connects as well as  of  survival  heaters and DC
>   harnesses.  With  the  Forward Service Link ,  low-rate data is
>   relayed from the EDRS System  Ground  Segment  to  COLKa  Terminal 
>   via  the  EDRS  GEO  satellite.  The  Return  Service  Link,  also 
>   via  the COLKa  Terminal  to  the  EDRS  Ground  segment  via  the 
>   EDRS  GEO  satellite,  provides high-rate  user  data  communications
>   between the COLKa Terminal and the EDRS Ground Segment, such as video,
>   sensor data, etc

[image]

The [eoPortal](https://directory.eoportal.org/web/eoportal/satellite-missions/content/-/article/iss-colka) article is good as usual. It relies on the paper already cited as a primary source.